# O entry point de um executável é o endereço da memória da função main()?

Tags: c, funções, assembly, debug

#### hello.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void){ // << entry point
    printf("Hello World!");
}
```

#### hello.asm

```
    global  _main 
    extern  _printf

    section .text
_main: ; << entry point
    push    message
    call    _printf
    add     esp, 4
    ret
message:
    db  'Hello, World!', 10, 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grosso modo, sim. Não é que precisa ser, mas geralmente é, pelo menos é o padrão. Sempre tem que começar executar por algum lugar e este é o mais óbvio.